# How do I display a modalpopupextender from a server side button click?

Tags: vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have an Ajax `ModalPopUpExtender` which works fine when launched by the target control, but what I want to do is launch it from a server side `Button_Click` event in VB.

This is because I want to check some variables before launching the `ModalPopUpExtender`.

I have tried the `.show` method which works fine on an initial `PageLoad` event when there is no post back, but the method won't work from an `asp:button`'s `onclick` event or from a post back event.

I have given the `ModalPopUpExtender` a dummy button to target as you can't run one without the `TargetControlID` being set. The dummy control is visible.

As the `.show` method works on a `PageLoad` event I know the `ModalPopUpExtender` is set up correctly, but what could be stopping it from running from a server-side event?

Here's my code:

```
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender
ID="mp1"
runat="server"
PopupControlID="Panel1"
TargetControlID="btnShowPopUp"                                                                      CancelControlID="btnClose"
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
```

```vb
Sub btnShow_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        if myVariable = 1 then

           mp1.show

        End if

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to Visual Vincent for sorting the format of my question - I'm not a regular poster here so detail on the correct etiquette isn't my forte!  Vincent, feel free to correct my answer too!

Answer (score 1):

After searching on more permutations of my question I finally found the answer in an existing answer on the site.  The target control has to be a hidden field object, not another button.

The full answer is at:

[ASP.NET: ModalPopupExtender prevents button click event from firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877551/asp-net-modalpopupextender-prevents-button-click-event-from-firing?rq=1)